# How can I set fields on an input hidden with Mechanize ?

Tags: javascript, forms, perl, www-mechanize

I select the form to change the page.
But the input is hidden.

Here is the html code :

```
<form id="form_pager" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="txtPage" name="page">

                <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('1');">&lt;&lt;</a>
                        <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('1');">Précédent</a>
            <span id="pager">


                                <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('1');">1</a>&nbsp;
                                            <strong>2</strong>&nbsp;
                                            <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('3');">3</a>&nbsp;
                                            <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('4');">4</a>&nbsp;
                                            <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('5');">5</a>&nbsp;

            </span>
                <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('3');">Suivant</a>
                        <a class="link-paginador" href="javascript:navigatePage('5');">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </form>
```

Here is my code :

```
$form = $mech->form_id('form_pager');
$mech->set_fields('txtPage' => 'page='.$nbpage);
$mech->click();
```

I've tried to change the status of the input like that :

```
foreach my $forms ($mech->forms()) {
    map { $_->readonly(0) } $forms->inputs();
}
```

But It doesn't work.

Have you some idea please ? Thanks !

Comment: The field name is `page` and not `txtPage`, e.g. try `$mech->set_fields( page => $nbpage )`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#Why-do-I-get-Input-fieldname-is-readonly).

One problem might be, that [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) does not evaluate Javascript.

You can try to use [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox), which can evaluate javascript or you can use [`WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aPhantomJS)

Thinks you need to know when you use want to use one of them:

- `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` uses your installed Firefox to execute, so you need to have Firefox installed
- `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS` uses [`phantomjs`](http://phantomjs.org/). So you need to have that installed when you want to use `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`.
- `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS` is complete without a screen, so you cant see the page. One part to *see* what the page would look like, is to use the `content_as_png` method. For further information about this, you can take a look at the POD.

Just use javascript after that to change the value.

---

Another problem might be the call of `set_fields`.

```
# i'm not sure if this works
$mech->set_fields('page' => $nbpage);

# form WWW::Mechanize::FAQ
# when you have warnings on:
{
   local $^W = 0;
   $mech->field( page => $nbpage );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but the first comment : The field name is page and not txtPage, e.g. try $mech->set_fields( page => $nbpage ) is the correct anwswer. I don't use javascript, I only fill out the hidden form with the correct field.

Comment: can be such a simple typo :), glad to help you :)